# Finding total number of descendants of each child in a tree

Tags: search, tree, graph-theory

I need to find the total number of children and descendants for all nodes in a 'm-ary' tree (is that the right name?).

E.g. In the below tree. 1 has six total descendants, 2 has three, 3 has one etc.

Does this problem have a name or terminology in graph theory that I can search to find efficient answers? I have to be careful with the time complexity.

```
     1
    /\
   2  3
  /\   \
 4  5   6
     \
      7
```

Sorry for the poor question, I'm stumbling my way through CS theory and trying to find the right terminology to Google my question. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can write an algorithm that combines Depth-First Search and a bit of Dynamic Programming. The idea is to do DF Search and store in an array of integers - let's call it **desc**[node] - the number of descendants for each node. Base case - a leaf, the number of descendants will be 0. Otherwise, for an internal node, the number of descendants will be:
the sum of its children values of **desc** + the number of children nodes (When I say children, I mean direct children).